# Unable to connect to device with Marshmallow for wireless debugging. Getting (10061) error

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to connect to an Android device with Marshmallow for wireless debugging.

```
C:\...\sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 192.168.1.103:5555  
unable to connect to 192.168.1.103:5555: cannot connect to 192.168.1.103:5555: 
    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

I also tried `adb connect "192.168.1.103:5556"` and `"adb connect 192.168.1.103"` but ended up with same result.

The first command above used to work fine on my OnePlus Two before the Marshmallow update.

Any help on how to do wireless debugging on Marshmallow?

Comment: After getting the next update, I got the "Android USB Device" entry for my OnePlus Two and I updated the driver using Samsung Android Debugging driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am also using the One Plus two and updated to marshmallow 2 weeks ago . i have the same issue

try to kill your adb sever then try again .

**adb kill-server**

you should use 5556 port number not 5555 anymore

if its not working connect your phone via usb cable then restart the adb into wireless mode

**adb tcpip 5556**

then try to connect your phone with the port no 5556 (eg ip:5556) after connected you can remove your usb cable

it worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But even after trying the above adb connect I still get the same error. adb tcpip command doesn't work because the device USB doesn't get recognized.

Comment: Have you checked the one plus drivers properly installed . you can check that in device manager

Comment: Finally, after an update to the OS, I was able to see the device in device manager and update it with Samsung Android Device Driver. Now it is working fine. Thanks for your replies Sridhar.

Comment: Only 5555 is working here on a LG G3 with A6.0. 5556 not working, and FYI, the usb connection was 5037.

Comment: I wonder: WHY is the wireless connection features for debugging not a part of the Android Studio menu system as a "one click" feature?

Answer (score 0):

Connect the Android device with the computer using your USB cable.
Restart adb in tcpip mode

```
adb tcpip 5556
```

Now try to reconnect the android device.

Answer (score 0):

at first ping your Android Device IP from pc and ping your PC IP from Android Terminal Emulator make shore got replay (it means wireless connecting is stable and no firewall problem)

connect USB chek "adb devices" in command line 
in this level you must have device name (esle must use other command likd eadb kill-server & adb start-server or chek device driver)

make your Device conncet first and work truly (many reason like your device driver and other thing must cheked in this case)

after that try "adb connect 192.168.1.3:5555"  (your device IP And always POST is 5555 and some time 5556)

if got error like (10061) test this "adb tcpip 5555"

after that tray again "adb connect 192.168.1.3:5555"

if this doset work unplug usb connection and connect again and tray one more time

after connecting to device you device ip display in devices list in ADT now you must unplug USB  if lost connection , dont wory just try  "adb connect 192.168.1.3:5555"  one more time but whitout USB cable (it just for first time wireless connecting need usb)